# Javascript, Working with array of objects. Take string, seperate by comma, and assign values to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object, debugging

I'm pretty new to Javascript and would appreciate any help.

So taking a string that looks like this: `"John Doe, 5554443333, Jane Doe, 5555555555"`

We are to assign each person to an object, then assign this object to an array, and  print the array to display our players. The expected output would be:

```
[{ player: 'John Doe', contact: 5554443333}, { player: 'Jane Doe', contact: 5555555555}]
```

my current Output is:

```
[{ player: 'Jane Doe', contact: 5555555555}, , { player: 'Jane Doe', contact: 5555555555}]
```

So the current problem is that it puts two comma's between the player objects, and also that it is listing the second player twice.

My code is as follows:

```
function playerManager(players) 
{

  var blank = [];  // blank array to return per requirements (nil, none, null, or empty string)
  var info = players.split(','); // Split our input string, into a string array, split at comma
  var data = []; // Create array to hold our players, then return.

  // function to create player 
  var player =
  {

  player: "name",
  contact: "contact"

  };

    // check if our string is empty, nil, none, or null, if it is , return our blank array 
    if(players == "" || players == "nil" || players == "None" || players == "null")
    {

    return blank;

    }

      for( i = 0; i < info.length - 1; i+=2)
      {

      player.player = info[i];
      player.contact = info[i+1];

      data[i] = player; 

      }

    return data;

}
```

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Please ignore the bad comment that labels my object a function (it was previously a constructor) and also the if statement is correct, as we are to check the string for certain key words or blank. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

So there's a couple of things going wrong here.

Easy one first:  because of the way you're iterating, `i+=2`, you're pushing the second object into the third, or `i[2]`, location.

An easy way to fix is to iterate by one (`i++`) up to `info.length / 2`, but use `i * 2` in your function

Ex:

```js
for( i = 0; i < info.length / 2; i++)
   {
      player.player = info[i * 2];
      player.contact = info[i * 2 + 1];

      data[i] = player; 
  }
```

Now the tougher bit.  When you assign an object to a variable, and either assign it to another variable or push it into an array, you're not **creating** a whole new object - you're simply referring to the exact same object, but with another name.

Here's a little snippet to demonstrate:

```js
var a = {name: 'Joe'};
var b = a;
a.name = 'George';
console.log(b.name); // This will output 'George'
```

The simplest fix for you, I think, is to simply push an "anonymous" object [that's probably a misnomer] into the array.

Further refactoring our loop from earlier:

```js
    for( i = 0; i < info.length / 2; i++)
       {
          data[i] = {
            player: info[i * 2],
            contact: info[i * 2 + 1]
          } 
      }
```

And finally, one more small edit - the best way to "push" an item into an array at the end is to use `Array.prototype.push`, which will automatically fix the "extra comma" issue.

So finally, here's what your code should look like:

```js
        for( i = 0; i < info.length / 2; i++)
           {
              data.push({
                player: info[i * 2],
                contact: info[i * 2 + 1]
              });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, the problem is, when you creating a player with info and then insert it into an player array in first round, your playerArr[0] is referencing to the player you created(which is an object). So far there is no problem. But when it goes round two, you updated the player object, which also make the playerArr[0] changed too! It is because playerArr[0] is actually a pointer which pointing to the player object( and you just updated it)!

This should work:

```js
function playerManager(players) 
{
  var info = players.split(','); // Split our input string, into a string array, split at comma
  var data = []; // Create array to hold our players, then return.
    

    for( i = 0; i < info.length/2; i++)
    {
      data[i] = {player:info[i*2],contact:info[i*2+1]}; 
    }

    return data;

}

console.log(playerManager("John Doe, 5554443333, Jane Doe, 5555555555"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are incremented your `for..loop` with `i+=2` and you are pushing value like this

```
 data[i] = player;
```

So initially for `0` index is right but after next increment `i` will be `2`. And next value will assign on `2` index so your `1` index will be empty.

So instead of assigning value in array index you could use [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method inside of for loop.

**DEMO**

```js
const str = "John Doe, 5554443333, Jane Doe, 5555555555";

function playerManager(players) {
  let arr = players.split(','),
    data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    data.push({
      player: arr[i],
      contact: arr[i + 1],
    })
  }
  return data;
}

console.log(playerManager(str))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and shorter alternative in a declarative style, assuming the player name and contact are always in the same order:

```
const input = 'John Doe, 5554443333, Jane Doe, 5555555555';
const result = input.split(',').map(str => str.trim()).reduce((all, item, i, arr) => {

    if (i % 2 === 1) {
        all.push({player: arr[i-1], contact: Number(item)});
    } 
    return all;

}, []);

console.log(result);
```